# Struggling with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

Suppose I have 3 Models like this (not sure if this is correct):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :points, through: :progress
end

class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :progress
end
```

(The Progress table has `user_id` and `lesson_id` fields.)

How would I make it so calling `@user.points` would return the amount of entries into the `Progress` table. Also, how would I build a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :progresses
  has_many :lessons, through: :progresses
end

class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :progresses
end
```

Comment: What i have posted in my answer would work with progresses table having user_id and lesson_id. user.progresses would return all the progress that that has the user_id as user.id

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up the association for `progress` on your `User` model, so that the `through` association will work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :progress
  has_many :points, through: :progress
end
```

Then you'll need to define a method (or relation) of `points` on your `Progress` table.  Or, if you simply want a count of records, you could do:  `@user.points.size`

Comment: How would I make that work if in the `Progresses` table there is `user_id` and `lesson_id`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If you have both of those, then the relation in the `User` table would be `belongs_to` or `has_one`.